# Алгоритм поиск сгруппированных элементов в таблице путем подбора

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Всем привет. Возможно такого решения не существует, но попытаться стоит - нужно придумать алгоритм (если вообще возможно) для такой задачи:

Имеются некоторые абстрактные элементы со свойствами. У каждого элемента есть строковое свойство, которое я могу менять. Некоторое количество таких элементов используются для отображения в таблице (для вопроса буду использовать excel). У таблицы настроены фильтры и группировки. Фильтры приводят к тому, что некоторые элементы вообще не отображаются в таблице (их надо как-то отсеять), а группировки приводят к "схлопыванию" - т.е. одна строка в таблице может содержать в себе несколько элементов, сгруппированных по какому-то свойству. Менять настройки фильтраций и группировок нельзя. Нужно получить элементы в той последовательности, в которой они отображаются в таблице. При этом имеется возможность менять только одно свойство у элемента (которое не влияет на фильтрацию и группировку).

Описывать словами бесполезно, поэтому давайте с примером. Имеем, допустим 5 элементов. У этих 5 элементов есть некоторое числовое свойство по которому они группируются. Если в этом свойстве нет значения, то оно не отображается в таблице. Напомню, что я не могу знать, что это за свойство и не могу его проверять.

```
var element1 = new {Integer = 100};
var element2 = new {Integer = 200};
var element3 = new {Integer = 200};
var element4 = new {Integer = 0};
var element5 = new {Integer = 300};
```

В таблице это будет выглядеть так (element4 фильтруется и не попадает в таблицу):

[image: Таблица1]

Из таблицы я могу сразу узнать, что конечный результат (а это будет коллекция списков) будет иметь 3 позиции.

Если я в некоторое текстовое поле этих элементов добавлю различные значения (например, просто число по порядку), то могу получить такой вариант:

[image: Таблица2]

Во второй строке ячейка "Строковое поле" пустая, так как у элементов будет разное значение текстового поля.

Анализируя таблицу после этого шага, я уже могу получить все "одиночные" элементы: element1 попадает в первый список результирующей коллекции, element5 попадает в 3 список результирующей коллекции. При этом я знаю, что 1-ую и 3-ую строку таблицы мне больше не надо проверять.

И вот на этом месте мои идеи закончились. Т.е. сейчас я могу:
1. Выяснить сколько конечных списков должен получить
2. Найти и выбрать все "одиночные" (не сгруппированные элементы)
3. Запомнить в каких строках были "одиночные" элементы, чтобы эти строки больше не проверять

Теперь мне нужно найти сгруппированные элементы с учетом элементов, которые вообще не попадают в таблицу. Самое главное условие - в столбце "Строковое поле" значение отображается только тогда, когда оно совпадает у всех элементов этой строки.

Сначала я подумал делать так: брать один элемент из оставшихся, писать ему какое-то уникальное значение. Затем брать следующий и писать ему тоже самое значение. После этого шага проверять таблицу. Если в ячейке появилось это значение, значит эти два элемента относятся к строке. Если не появилось - брать следующий элемент, добавлять ему значение и снова проверять таблицу. Проблема в том, что таким образом я могу никогда не найти нужных группировок, так как на каком-то шаге добавлю элемент, который не должен быть в текущей группе...

В общем - возможно ли придумать алгоритм? Надеюсь, описал достаточно подробно

Comment: Обычно данные перед группировкой сортируются по столбцам, по которым производится группировка. После этого агрегирующие функции применяются каждой  из групп.

Comment: @MaxU сортировка, группировка и фильтрация производятся приложением для которого я пишу дополнение. И нет возможности их обрабатывать (недостаточное АПИ)